# Echo a previously established array in php works in normal php but not in echo

Tags: php, ajax, youtube-data-api

I am trying to echo an array of objects in php with the youtube api.  I can get it to work fine when it is in a normal inline php code but I wanted to use pjax to develope the site I am using so I need it to echo into the $body.  The code I have is as follows

```
 <?php 
 $keyword = "My Keyword";
 $key = 'My API Key';
 $file = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?videoEmbeddable=true&videoType=any&part=id%2Csnippet&q=$keyword&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&maxResults=8&key={$key}");

 $decoded = json_decode($file, true);

 $entries = $decoded['items'];

 if (!empty($entries)) {
      for($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++) {
          $thumb = $entries[$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'];
          $title = $entries[$i]['snippet']['title'];
          $video = $entries[$i]['id']['videoId'];
          $content[]= "<a class=\"video-toggle\" href=\"http://youtube.com/embed/$video?modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#videoModal\"><img src=\"$thumb\" alt=\"Play Video\"><h3 class=\"recommendations-title\">$title</h3></a>";
      }           
 }

 if (!empty($content)) : 
 foreach($content as $thumb) :
 $recommendedvideos = "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ts-12       video-box'>$thumb </div> [$i]";
 endforeach; 
 endif; 
 ?>

 <?php $body = "$recommendedvideos"; ?>
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'):
 else: 
 echo '<div id="main">'.$body.'</div>';
```

For some reason I can only get the last result to display and don't really know why.  I have tried multiple different solutions but can't really seem to figure out why I only returns the last one in the array to the page.  Like I said it works fine on normal inline php but not in the echo.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to echo `echo '<div id="main">'.$body.'</div>';`?

Comment: The above portion <?php $body = "$recommendedvideos"; ?> is loaded by the pjax library and if it is not then the code will echo the echo '<div id="main">'.$body.'</div>'; so the html is stipulated in the above portion and <?php $body = "<html>$recommendedvideos"</html>; ?> and if someone just lands on the page and pjax isn't loading it then it will echo <div id="main">'.$body.'</div>'; hopefully that all makes sense i may have not explained it that well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you are not concatenating your info for `$recommendedvideos`. Init it before your loop: `$recommendedvideos = ""` and then ammend it in the loop:

```
$recommendedvideos .= "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ts-12 video-box'>$thumb </div> [$i]";
```

As you loop over `$content` you keep re-writing `$recommendedvideos`

Comment: So If write it like $recommendedvideos.= " <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ts-12 video-box'>$thumb </div> "; It returns the right data but keep getting the error Undefined variable: recommendedvideos

Comment: Not sure what you mean by concentrating content then loop maybe I am just reading this wrong or dont understand sorry.

Comment: Ok so I read that wrong  concatenating got it working now thanks for your help this works